# create xml using javascript and pass to ajax

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing, xml-serialization

I have to created a dynamic menu using JavaScript(Tree structure). And based on the structure an XML is created and save into a variable and pass [image: This is the menu structure]to the server side. Please help me for solving this..

Comment: So what is the problem

Comment: I don't know How to how to create it dynamically and I am new in this...

Comment: what kind of technology are you plan to use? Java, PHP, nodes?

Comment: Using ASP.NET Technology is using